# Using LocalStorage to save files content

Tags: javascript, file

I would like to put file content (with blob) in localstorage in JavaScript. But localstorage is limited at 5MB on Firefox and only Firefox and Opera can increase the size of Dom Storage (localstorage). I've succeeded to store a video file on localstorage :

```
var urlVideo = "sample.mp4";
var videoStorage = localStorage.getItem("sample.mp4");
var videoElement = document.getElementById("video");
var videoSource = document.getElementById("source");

if (videoStorage)
{
    // Loaded from localstorage
    videoElement.setAttribute("src", videoStorage);
}
else
{
    // Loaded online
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        blob,
        fileReader = new FileReader();

    xhr.open("GET", urlVideo, true);
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            blob = new Blob([xhr.response], { type: "video/mp4" });
            fileReader.onload = function (evt) {
                var result = evt.target.result;
                try {
                    localStorage.setItem("sample.mp4", result);
                }
                catch (e) {
                    console.log("Failed : " + e);
                }
            };
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            videoElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        }
    }, false);
    xhr.send();
}
```

So I would like to have a simple method in JavaScript to store big files content in local on every browsers without some hack on browser settings. So I heard that it would be possible with indexedDB but it seems more complicated.

Comment: There are libraries you can use to simplify indexDb use. As for *"all browsers"* may run into support issues on older browsers.

Comment: With `indexedDB` is possible to store large objects, but I am not sure what are you asking here.

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla I would like the same thing without hacks and with indexedDB if is possible.