# User-uploaded image as game background

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying fix this game for a friend (so I don't exactly know what all his code is doing).  What I want to do is take an image uploaded by the user and set it as the background permanently even after closing app. Here's what I have right now:

The assets are loaded here:

```
game.stage.backgroundColor = '#000000';
game.load.image('GameFrame.png', 'assets/GameFrame.png');
game.load.image('game_frame', 'assets/GameFrame.png');
```

The default image "game_frame" is set here:

```
create: function()
    {
        this.frameGroup = game.add.group();
        this.game_frame_background = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 
          'game_frame_background');
        this.frameGroup.add(this.game_frame_background);
        this.frameGroup.add(this.wordGroup);
        this.game_frame = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'game_frame');
        this.frameGroup.add(this.game_frame);

        this.frameGroup.x = GAME_WIDTH / 2 - this.game_frame.width / 2;
        this.frameGroup.y = GAME_HEIGHT / 2 - this.game_frame.height / 2;
    }
```

Lastly, I put the file input js in the HTML file:

```
<body>
<div id="gameDiv">  
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('file-input').click();">Change Background</button>
    <input id="file-input" type="file" name="name" style="display: none;"/>
</div>
</body>
```

This is where I'm stuck.  I think I need to either change the name of the user's image to "GameFrame.png" OR I need to load the user's image as an asset replacing "assets/GameFrame.png" asset.  But I don't know how to do either of these things.

Comment: If it's pure html5 web app then maybe this can be helpful for handling files (File API/Filereader API): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: I read this at some point and considered displaying the image as URL object, but I think that would only work until the user ends the session.  Maybe I can save the URL some place and retrieve it on the next session?  Idk I'm snowballing at this point

Comment: An url can be saved using a cookie or in localStorage, but I doubt it's possible to link to a local file outside browser context. Maybe the file(reader) api provides a way to move the image into the browser cache, like where it stores offline webpages. Otherwise look into converting the image data (Blob) to a string and store that in localStorage or indexedDB (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224478/using-localstorage-to-save-files-content) ). A plugin like [localforage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) may be helpful with that.

Comment: Another means of storing in the browser is html5 [AppCache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache). Just be aware it's deprecated.

Comment: Noice thanks for the leads!  I was hoping there was an elegant solution, but I'll do more research starting with the options you've mentioned and see if I can't MacGyver some janky solution together -- it doesn't have to be pretty it just has to work :p

Comment: Lol.. good luck with that. Then getting it to display is the easy part ;)